# jquery change attr href in ie8 changes the text

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my code below works in all browsers, however in IE8 and IE7 a link appears to not be preserving the text.

Example of what's happening:

```
<a href="http//site.com/">view site</a>
```

After my code in IE

```
<a href="http//site.com/">http//site.com/</a>
```

I did some searching and there are multiple problems bugs logged around this.

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2, but also tried 1.10 and no difference.

```
var replacer = $('.ir a, .tk a');
//apply menu to inner links
$(replacer).each(function () {
    //get page param with getmenu    
    var getmenu = location.href.split("&menu")[1];
    if (typeof getmenu === 'undefined') {
        getmenu = "&menu=1";
    };
    var attr = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", attr + getmenu);
});
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example and post the HTML you're using this with in your question?

Comment: I would but I can't run jsfiddle in IE8.

Comment: build it in chrome, then navigate to it as /embeded in ie8

Answer (score 1):

This still seems to be an issue with the latest jQuery (1.11.3) four years after it was reported. The simplest solution is to just reset the text after you change the href attribute with jQuery.

Since jQuery changes the text as well as the href, just cache the text before you change it and set the text back to what it was like this:

```
// Keep a copy of the text before jQuery messes it up.
var text = $(this).text();
// Change the href.
var attr = $(this).attr("href");
$(this).attr("href", attr + getmenu);
// Set the text back to what it was.
$(this).text(text);
```

This is quite safe to use for all browser versions so you don't need to check if it's IE<9 before applying this workaround.